# Не останавливается цикл

Tags: python, разработка-игр

**Программка крестики нолики**

---

python цикл не хочет останавливаться, хочу понять почему и как такое исправлять

````
from random import randint

l = 3 # размер матрицы
A = [[0] * l for i in range(l)] # матрица игры
B = [['*'] * l for i in range(l)] # матрица для вывода
C = 0 # флаг окончания игры
k1, k3 = 1, 1 # коэффициенты для проверки победы

def print_matrix(): # функция для печати матрицы
    print('\033[33mМатрица: ')
    for row in B:
        print(row)

def input_coords(player): # функция для ввода координат
    a, b = map(int, input(f'\033[37mИгрок {player} введите координаты через запятую в формате x,y: ').split(','))
    while A[a - 1][b - 1] != 0: # проверка на занятость клетки
        print('\033[31m\nДанное место занято')
        a, b = map(int, input(f'\033[37m\nИгрок {player} введите координаты через запятую в формате x,y: ').split(','))
    return a, b

def check_win(k1, k3): # функция для проверки победы
    global C # обращение к глобальной переменной C
    for i in range(l): # проверка по горизонтали и вертикали
        if A[i][0] == A[i][1] == A[i][2] == k1 or A[0][i] == A[1][i] == A[2][i] == k1:
            print(f'\033[32m\nВыиграл игрок {k3}')
            C = 1 # установка флага в 1
            return # выход из функции

    if A[0][0] == A[1][1] == A[2][2] == k1 or A[0][2] == A[1][1] == A[2][0] == k1: # проверка по диагоналям
        print(f'\033[32m\nВыиграл игрок {k3}')
        C = 1
        return

    if 0 not in A: # проверка на заполнение матрицы
        print('\033[32m\nВариантов ходов не осталось(')
        C = 1
        return


def bot_move(d): # функция для хода бота
    global C # обращение к глобальной переменной C
    if d == 1: # сложность 1 - случайный ход
        a = randint(0, l-1)
        b = randint(0, l-1)
        while A[a][b] != 0: # проверка на занятость клетки
            a = randint(0, l-1)
            b = randint(0, l-1)
        A[a][b] = -1
        B[a][b] = 'O'

    elif d == 2: # сложность 2 - умный ход
        p = False # флаг для выхода из цикла
        for i in range(l): # цикл по всем клеткам матрицы
            for j in range(l):
                if A[i][j] == 0: # если клетка свободна
                    A[i][j] = -1 # пробуем поставить туда O
                    B[i][j] = 'O'
                    check_win(-1, 2) # проверяем победу бота
                    if C == 1: # если бот выиграл
                        p = True # устанавливаем флаг в True
                        break # выходим из внутреннего цикла
                    else: # если бот не выиграл
                        A[i][j] = 0 # возвращаем клетку в исходное состояние
                        B[i][j] = '*'
            if p: # если флаг True
                break # выходим из внешнего цикла

        if not p: # если флаг False
            for i in range(l): # цикл по всем клеткам матрицы
                for j in range(l):
                    if A[i][j] == 0: # если клетка свободна
                        A[i][j] = 1 # пробуем поставить туда X
                        B[i][j] = 'X'
                        check_win(1, 1) # проверяем победу игрока
                        if C == 1: # если игрок выиграл
                            A[i][j] = -1 # ставим туда O, чтобы помешать ему
                            B[i][j] = 'O'
                            C = 0 # сбрасываем флаг окончания игры
                            p = True # устанавливаем флаг в True
                            break # выходим из внутреннего цикла
                        else: # если игрок не выиграл
                            A[i][j] = 0 # возвращаем клетку в исходное состояние
                            B[i][j] = '*'
                if p: # если флаг True
                    break # выходим из внешнего цикла

        if not p: # если флаг False
            bot_move(1) # делаем случайный ход

    print("\033[37mХодит бот")
    print_matrix() # печатаем матрицу

print('\033[33mДобро пожаловать в игру крестики нолики!\n')
q = int(input('\033[36mЕсли хотите играть с другом введите 1, а еcли с ботом 2: '))
while q not in [1, 2]: # проверка на ошибки
    print('\n\033[31mНет других вариантов!\n ')
    q = int(input('\033[36mЕсли хотите играть с другом введите 1, а еcли с ботом 2:'))

print_matrix() # печатаем матрицу
print('Координаты: \n  1  2  3\n1| \n2| \n3|')

if q == 1: # игра с другом
    while C == 0: # пока не закончилась игра
        a, b = input_coords(1) # ход первого игрока
        A[a - 1][b - 1] = 1
        B[a - 1][b - 1] = 'X'
        print_matrix() # печатаем матрицу
        check_win(1, 1) # проверяем победу первого игрока
        if C == 1: # если он выиграл
            break # выходим из цикла

        a, b = input_coords(2) # ход второго игрока
        A[a - 1][b - 1] = -1
        B[a - 1][b - 1] = 'O'
        print_matrix() # печатаем матрицу
        check_win(-1, 2) # проверяем победу второго игрока
        if C == 1: # если он выиграл
            break # выходим из цикла


if q == 2: # игра с ботом
    d = int(input('\033[36m\nВведите желаемую сложность от 1 до 2: '))
    while d not in [1, 2]: # проверка на ошибки
        print('\n\033[31mНет других вариантов!\n ')
        d = int(input('\033[36m\nВведите желаемую сложность от 1 до 2: '))

    while C == 0: # пока не закончилась игра
        a, b = input_coords(1) # ход первого игрока
        A[a - 1][b - 1] = 1
        B[a - 1][b - 1] = 'X'
        print_matrix() # печатаем матрицу
        check_win(1, 1) # проверяем победу первого игрока
        if C == 1: # если он выиграл
            break # выходим из цикла

        bot_move(d) # ход бота
        check_win(-1, 2) # проверяем победу бота
        if C == 1: # если бот выиграл
            break # выходим из цикла


    print('\033[32mСпасибо за игру!') ```
````

Comment: в этом коде примерно 100500 циклов. О каком их них речь?

Comment: Сорри, забыл уточнить ошибка в циклах игры  while C==0:

Comment: я запустил, ввел координаты, игра сразу остановилась со словами "Вариантов ходов не осталось".

Comment: В коде есть присвоение C = 1, но нигде не нашел, в какой момент C может стать обратно 0.

Comment: Ну цикл с C должен остановиться при установлении ему другого значения, C присваивается 1 если кто либо из игроков побеждает и цикл ведь должен остановиться... Я просто начал изучать пайтон не так давно, и заступорился на таком простом задании, а знакомые также только начавшие изучать тоже не понимают в чём проблема

Comment: @SwaD это незачем, тут нет повторной игры. Когда C==1, игра выключается.

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка Нет, там есть повторная игра, просто я вырезал её

Comment: А слабо тоже самое но в десять строк кода?)

Comment: @Александр уфффф, ну еслииии без режима с ботом, то можно попробовать 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша главная ошибка в том месте, где вы проверяете, остались ли нули в массиве A:

```
if 0 not in A: # проверка на заполнение матрицы
        print('\033[32m\nВариантов ходов не осталось(')
        C = 1
        return
```

Вот как выглядит массив A:

[image: Массив А]

В нём внутри вложенные массивы, соответственно нули находятся в них, а не в массиве A. Поэтому программа и "говорит", что игра окончена. Вам нужно заменить код, который я написал выше, на этот:

```
if 0 not in A[0] and 0 not in A[1] and 0 not in A[2]:
        print('\033[32m\nВариантов ходов не осталось(')
        C = 1
        return
```

У меня в этом случае всё работает, интересная игра:)

Comment: Спасибо, я не знал что это так работает :)

Comment: Не за что)) Обращайтесь